# Reactjs: Api call with axios

Tags: reactjs

I am new to Reactjs, I am working on my application which has a backend with .NetCore. And I am using reactjs for my frontend. I have an api response from .netcore which has two types `Internal and External`, i.e. I have merged 2 api calls together to make a single response. The way I did it is below.

**.NetCore Code**

[image]

and the response I get is below

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "TestProductAzure",
        "description": "<p>While working with the EF Core Code-First approach, we create the classes for our domain entities first. Later, we’ll create the database from our code by using migrations. This is the opposite of the Database-First approach where we design our database first and then create the classes which match our database design.In the EF Core Code-First approach, we have full control over the code and the database is just a store without any logic. This approach is helpful in situations where we are starting with the development of a new project and we don’t have a clear picture of how our database should look like yet.We don’t have to worry about creating and updating the database. We can just make the changes in our code and then sync everything easily with the database. The important thing to note is that the manual changes that we make to the database could be lost during migration. So we should make changes to the code only.</p>",
        "owner": "Seeded Company",
        "link": null,
        "url": "http://localhost:54729/api/product/1",
        "type": "Internal",
        "rank": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "TestProductForAzure",
        "description": null,
        "owner": "Seeded Company",
        "link": null,
        "url": "http://localhost:54729/api/product/3",
        "type": "Internal",
        "rank": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "example Home Page",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "link": "/search/product?url=http://www.example.com/glossary.shtml",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/glossary.shtml",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 0
    }
]
```

As in the response above you can see that there are different types of results i.e. `Internal and External`. For more clear picture you can see the frontend in react as below.

[image]

Now what I really want from react is a bit tricky, and I couldn't find anything on internet till now.
For my `Internal type products` I have another api which response with the information of the particular product forexample.

**if we hit on first result with postman i.e. `http://localhost:54729/api/product/1` we get**

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Product Details",
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "TestProductAzure",
        "heading": "Very Very Nice",
        "description": "<p>While working with the EF Core Code-First approach, we create the classes for our domain entities first. Later, we’ll create the database from our code by using migrations. This is the opposite of the Database-First approach where we design our database first and then create the classes which match our database design.In the EF Core Code-First approach, we have full control over the code and the database is just a store without any logic. This approach is helpful in situations where we are starting with the development of a new project and we don’t have a clear picture of how our database should look like yet.We don’t have to worry about creating and updating the database. We can just make the changes in our code and then sync everything easily with the database. The important thing to note is that the manual changes that we make to the database could be lost during migration. So we should make changes to the code only.</p>",
        "keywords": "Good, bad, best, abc edited",
        "posted": true,
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "RX Product e aaa",
            "description": "Abcde gfd"
        },
        "addedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "modifiedDate": "2019-06-24T15:36:00.3673344",
        "addedBy": null,
        "modifiedBy": {
            "id": "ca8a4731-9717-48d5-b938-1bcad369b345",
            "userName": "ArsTestAdmin",
            "email": "abcadmin@gmail.com"
        },
        "roles": []
    }
}
```

I want to call that api based on the type of particular product. If it is `External` it can redirect directly to the `url` when clicked otherwise, if it is `Internal` it should call the api get the information and put it in the other react page. I also have developed my `Internal Product Detail` also. You can see the code below.

**Code for the search results (What I have tried till now)**

```
import React from "react";
import Rating from "./rating";
import "./test.css";
import { fetchArticle } from "../../../_actions/article.action";
import ProductDetails from "../product-details/ProductDetails";
import Axios from "axios";
import { userService } from "../../../_services";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
export default function SingleSearchResult(props) {
  let result = props.result;

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="s130">
        {/* <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 col-sm-12 col-md-7"> */}

        <div className="col-lg">
          <div className="container">
            <h3 className="search-result-heading">
              <a
                id="click"

                target="_blank"
                // onClick={handleClick(props)}
                href={
                  result.type == "Internal"
                    ? handleClick(props.result)
                    : result.url
                }
              >

                {result.title}
              </a>{" "}
            </h3>

            {result.type == "Article" ? <p>by {result.author}</p> : ""}
            <Rating rating={result.rating} />
          </div>

          <a
            href={result.url}
            target="_blank"

          >
            {" "}
            <cite class="iUh30">{result.url}</cite>
            <br />{" "}
          </a>

          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function handleClick(props) {
  if (props.type == "Internal") {
    console.log(props.url);
  } else {
    return <Redirect to={props.url}></Redirect>;
  }
}
```

**Code For Product Details after Internal product is clicked**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ProductTabs from "./ProductTabs";
import Rating from "./Rating";
import SearchBar from "../search/search-bar";

function ProductDetails(props) {
  const product = props.product;

  console.log("Received product", product);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12">
          <SearchBar />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-1" />
        <div className="col-sm-8">
          <div
            className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"
            style={{ paddingBottom: "50px" }}
          >
            <div className="product-content product-wrap clearfix product-deatil">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                  <div className="product-image">
                    <div id="myCarousel-2" className="carousel">
                      <div className="carousel-inner">
                        <div className="item active">
                          {" "}
                          <img src={product.image} alt="" />{" "}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <h2 className="name">
                    {" "}
                    {product.title}{" "}
                    <small>
                      Product by <a>{product.company}</a>
                    </small>{" "}
                    <Rating rating={product.rating}></Rating>
                    <br />
                    <span className="fa fa-1x">
                      <h3>
                        {product.totalReviews} customer review
                        {product.totalReviews > 1 ? "s" : ""}
                      </h3>
                    </span>
                  </h2>

                  <hr />

                  <div className="certified">
                    <ul>
                      <li>Delivery time {product.deliveryTime}</li>
                      <li>Certified Quality Assured</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <hr />

                  <div>
                    <p>{product.description}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <ProductTabs></ProductTabs>
        </div>

        <div className="col-sm-3">
          <div className="card">
            {" "}
            <img
              src="/assets/images/abbott.png"
              alt="John"
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
            />
            <h1>{product.contact.name}</h1>
            <p className="cardTitle">{product.contact.title}</p>
            <p>{product.contact.organization}</p>
            <div style={{ margin: "24px 0" }}>
              <a href={product.contact.social.dribble}>
                <i className="fa fa-dribbble" />
              </a>
              <a href={product.contact.social.twitter}>
                <i className="fa fa-twitter" />
              </a>
              <a href={product.contact.social.linkedin}>
                <i className="fa fa-linkedin" />
              </a>
              <a href={product.contact.social.facebook}>
                <i className="fa fa-facebook" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <p>
              <button
                className="cardButton"
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModal"
              >
                Contact
              </button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  product: state.product.product
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductDetails);
```

**The Product Details Page looks like this**
[image]